# Using Visual Studio 2005 for buliding LynxOS applications

Tags: visual-studio, lynxos

I am trying to build application for LynxOS (Hard Real time OS). The best method so far is to use an add on called VisualLynx which attach itself to VS 6.0 and replaces its make system with its on cross compiler linker etc. VS 6.0 is a real pain to use, so I wanted to use VS 2005 but it seems there is no add on for VS 2005.
Is there a way to use what I already have (Visual Lynx for VS 6.0) on VS 2005.......
Its a tough one I guess but if there is any way it would be a big help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have typically cross compiled from linux for LynxOS builds.  In that regard, I have used either xemacs or eclipse for my IDE on Redhat.  Works like a champ.

Comment: I suppose that you could use eclipse on the Windows platform and that would allow you to use the same CDK that you are currently using.